# XAMPP permission denied on all conf files

Tags: apache, configuration, permissions, xampp

I want to make some changes to the apache conf file in my xampp application. However, I seem to be unable to alter permissions on the conf files in any way. I only seem to be able to access the conf whenever I mount, but can get permission over the files in any way.

Im running the lates XAMPP version 7.3.2 / PHP 7.3.2 on macOS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, I made a stupid mistake, I installed the XAMPP-VM instead of the normal installation. Switching to non VM obviously fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following method. (Not to compromise the security too much.)

1. Open Terminal in XAMPP VM
2. Go to the etc folder

> cd /opt/lampp/etc

3. Change the permission on the conf file.

> chmod 777 https.conf

4. Explore the mounted volume
5. Open "https.conf" file with any editor you prefer and modify the content.
6. Change the permission back on the conf file.

> chmod 644 https.conf